# How do I adjust my JS to account for the last days of the previous month?

Tags: javascript, date, calendar

I want to show "The last days of the offer" for example:

Offer days: 1, 2 and 3 of June 2023.

My code works fine, until I get to the start of a new month.

At the beginning of each month, it shows like this:

0, 1 and 2 of June 2023 but it should be 31, 1 and 2 of June 2023.

That is, I need to show the last day of the previous month instead of 0.

Or the last two days of the month, in this example: 30, 31 and 1 of June 2023.

PS: The date format may look wrong for English speakers, because it is in Portuguese format.

PPS: Usually I have to use it in more than one place on the same page.

PPPS: Sorry for the poor code, I'm learning.

```html
<span id="diaspromocao1"></span>
<span id="diaspromocao2"></span>
```

```
var months = new Array(12);
months[0] = "Janeiro";
months[1] = "Fevereiro";
months[2] = "Março";
months[3] = "April";
months[4] = "Maio";
months[5] = "Junho";
months[6] = "Julho";
months[7] = "Augosto";
months[8] = "Setembro";
months[9] = "Outobro";
months[10] = "Novembro";
months[11] = "Dezembro";

var current_date = new Date();
current_date.setDate(current_date.getDate() + 0);
month_value = current_date.getMonth();
day_value = current_date.getDate();
day_value1 = current_date.getDate() - 1;
day_value2 = current_date.getDate() - 2;                                        
year_value = current_date.getFullYear();

document.getElementById("diaspromocao1").innerHTML = + day_value2 + ", " + day_value1 + " e " + day_value + " de "+ months[month_value] + " de " + year_value;
document.getElementById("diaspromocao2").innerHTML = + day_value2 + ", " + day_value1 + " e " + day_value + " de "+ months[month_value] + " de " + year_value;
```

I don't know what else to do to resolve this. Would anyone here be able to help me out? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you use the `Date` object to go back to the previous days by doing `current_date.setDate(current_date.getDate() - 1)`, it will handle wrapping around. Here's a simpler example. Note that the month will also change (of course!):

```js
var current_date = new Date();
showMonthAndDay(current_date);
current_date.setDate(current_date.getDate() - 1);
showMonthAndDay(current_date);
current_date.setDate(current_date.getDate() - 1);
showMonthAndDay(current_date);

function showMonthAndDay(date) {
    console.log(`month = ${date.getMonth()}, day = ${date.getDate()}`);
}
```

---

Side note: `current_date.setDate(current_date.getDate() + 0);` doesn't do anything, you can just remove it.

Answer (score 1):

[getDate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) just returns the day of month as a number. So if it's the first day of a month (`1`) you will receive `0` after you subtracted one day.

This is not how temporal, arithmetic operations work on `Date`. You need to set the new value on the existing instance of `Date`. In case of an overflow (start/end of months for example) the class will take care of it.

```js
let date1 = new Date();
let date2 = new Date();

date1.setDate(date1.getDate() - 1);
date2.setDate(date2.getDate() - 2);

console.log(`Year: ${date1.getFullYear()} Month: ${date1.getMonth()} Day: ${date1.getDate()}`);
console.log(`Year: ${date2.getFullYear()} Month: ${date2.getMonth()} Day: ${date2.getDate()}`);
```

Also note that `Date` is mutable so you should work with individual instances for your separate dates.